# How to access files in Public Sites?

Tags: force.com-sites, files

I am using below query to get link for files

```
[SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId  FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId in (SELECT Id FROM Custom_Object__c where Parent__c != null)]
```

Code in VF page :

```
<apex:image url="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!ContentVersionMap[CList.ContentDocumentId]}"/>
```

Above query not returning any rows?

> Note : I have given view all access to both objects Custom_Object__c and Parent__c and Class is `without sharing`

Comment: can you make your class as without sharing?

Comment: I have added without sharing too.

Comment: can you get results of that querry in workbench?

Comment: Yes that page is working fine in standard user but not in sites.

Comment: The problem is ContentDocumentLink cant be accessed by Site user , from my experience.

Comment: Ohh! How can I expose files to site user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have one solution which might not be the ideal choice.

As we cannot use Guest Site user to access content document Link, we can use Some Other user credentials to do that.

1. Store a User Credentials UserName and Password in Custom Settings
2. In your Public Site's APex controller, Use Salesforce [Oauth2 UserName Password](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5) flow to get session id for the user whose creds you have stored in custom settings
3. Once you get the Session ID/access token, you can make a call to [SOQL endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) withe Query you mentioned and can  get result as its not running in guest user context
4. Parse that querry to get result and then display it on VF page

Comment: question: would NamedCredentials work as an alternative to saving userid/pw in custom settings? pw is masked in NamedCreds

Comment: one more possibility if we set visibility of ContentDocumentLink to `AllUsers`. then we are able to query it in site users context. Got to know from my colleague.

Comment: Then someone can literally access any links even by adding that Id in Url paras

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Opps!! My bad, setting visibility to `AllUsers` works for Communities not sites. Apologies!